# How to use the XQuery fn:id() function?

Tags: schema, xquery

I'm failing in my first attempt to get the `fn:id()` XQuery function to do something.

So far I have a document called bar.xml;

```
<bar>
    <foo id="a"/>
    <foo id="b"/>
    <foo id="c"/>
</bar>
```

And an XQuery;

```
doc('bar.xml')/fn:id(("a", "c"))
```

But everything I try just seems to return an empty set.

I have yet to learn XML schemas. Can `fn:id()` work without declaring a separate schema file for bar.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indicate that your id attributes are ids.

One way to do this is to add a schema or DTD to the document that specifies this.

The other (far easier) way is to use `xml:id` in place of `id` in your document.

On a related note, you may wish to use `element-with-id()` instead of `id()`.  `element-with-id()` does what `id()` was originally intended to do, and `id` remains in the specification for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Great, that did the trick - thank you. Replacing id with xml:id worked, for example replacing `<foo id="a"/>` with `<foo xml:id="a"/>` and leaving the xquery the same as in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: +1. You my also want to check out my blog entry about this: http://xqueryxpath.tumblr.com/post/8210950561/how-to-use-the-xquery-fnid-function