# xquery fn:id not working, even though type=xs:id seems to be declared correctly

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am working on an XSLT transformation that is running on a server with Altova. I need to adapt some stuff and working locally with Oxgen, using a saxon parser. For some reason, fn:id() does not work, it is returning an empty node. Explaining the rather complicated setup:

My input (input.xml):

```
<position id="pos_1">
    <protected>true</protected>
    <titel>Secret Business</titel>
    <entry id="entry_1">
        <title>Some Business</title>
        <year>2008</year>
    </entry>
</position>
```

A second input is read into a variable (see below), it looks like that (ProcessData.xml):

```
<goose:process-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.goose.org" xmlns:goose="http://www.goose.org" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.goose.org ProcessData.xsd">>
    <goose:Collection>
        <goose:Package id="entry_1">
            <goose:PID>1234-4321-asdf</goose:PID>
        </goose:Package>
 ....
```

My XSLT:

```
<!-- Reading in second input (process information) -->
<xsl:param name="process-data-path" select="xs:string('file:///home/documents/some/path/to/ProcessData.xml')"
<xsl:variable name="process-data" select="document($process-data-path)"
<!-- get the value of element <goose:PID> that corresponds to the id in 'input.xml' -->
<xsl:variable name="pid">
    <xsl:value-of select="fn:element-with-id(@id,$process-data)/goose:PID"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now I'm aware of the correct typing of id elements (here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269053/1717188 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369296/1717188). If I write `xml:id` in ProcessData.xml, it works fine. But this is not how the file is created. And the corresponding schema (ProcessData.xsd) does declare the id-Attribute as follows: `<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>`

Over the last hours, I had many ideas what could be wrong. One of them: Does the `type="xs:ID"`somehow get lost through reading the tree into a variable with `document()`?

Comment: Do you use Saxon EE if you want to use schema-based ID information? Have you enabled schema-validation in oXygen for the Saxon EE transformation scenario? Otherwise I don't think you can exploit the schema based declaration of ID values that the `id` function or the `element-with-id` function need.

Comment: I'm using SAXON EE 9.7.0.19.
How would I enable schema-validation in oxygen for my scenario?

Comment: See https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.0/ug-editor/topics/preferences-xslt-saxon8.html, you need to enable `lax` or `strict` validation in that dialog you can open by clicking the icon next to the select box where you select Saxon EE as the processor for your XSLT transformation.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot.